# What does так им и надо mean?

Tags: значения

Literally it means maybe "just what they need". But it is supposed to bear an ironic meaning, I guess. Right?

Comment: it's not slang, it's a commonly used idiom

Comment: @Quassnoi's answer is not complete: "так [им/ему/ей/вам/мне/...] и надо" is ALWAYS ironic. It's definitely not a good idea to say this after smth like "they are getting married" :)

Comment: @Mikant: hi and welcome to Russian.SE! What exactly in my answer would suggest such a usage?

Comment: @Quassnoi, your answer is ok, but there's only a translation of the idiom which imo doesn't answer the real question: `But it is supposed to bear an ironic meaning, I guess. Right?`

Comment: @Mikant: I don't think it's any more ironic than "they had it coming" or "serves them right".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means "they deserve it" (of a bad thing), "they had it coming", "it serves them right".

This passage from "The Brothers Karamazov" by Dostoyevsky:

> — Сумасшедший, ведь ты убил его! — крикнул Иван. — Так ему и надо! — задыхаясь, воскликнул Дмитрий.

in English translation reads:

> ‘Madman! You’ve killed him!’ cried Ivan. ‘Serve him right!’ shouted Dmitri breathlessly.

Comment: Useful to note: translation by Constance Garnett.